# Sull'uso di "salvo"

Tags: word-usage, grammar

Nelle pubblicità di auto alla radio si parla spesso di offerte di finanziamenti "*salvo* approvazione [nome banca]".

Oggi stesso, mentre facevo un bonifico, è comparsa l'informazione che il bonifico sarà addebitato "*salvo* buon fine".

> [Salvo](http://dizionari.corriere.it/dizionario_italiano/S/salvo.shtml): In funzione di cong., col sign. di “a meno di”, introduce una frase eccettuativa implicita con il v. all'inf.: l'opera non si potrà realizzare, s. ridurre di molto il costo; nell'uso colloquiale, equivale a “ma con la possibilità di”: dice di non avere bisogno di nulla, s. poi chiederti un prestito
>
> [Salvo](http://www.zanichellibenvenuti.it/wordpress/?p=4508) → usata da sola: col significato di eccetto, all’infuori di ⇒ posso mangiare tutto, salvo la cioccolata;

**Perché in ambito bancario/borsistico ([4b](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/salvo/)) è permesso quest'uso di *salvo* con il significato di *previo*?**

Comment: In effetti è curioso che in genere “salvo” come preposizione introduce il caso che si vuole escludere, mentre nell'uso bancario e mercantile (ma anche in espressioni antiquate come “salvo il vero”) introduce ciò che si auspica.

Comment: Esiste anche “fatto salvo” e relative variazioni di numero e genere, che ho sempre interpretato così: quanto è “fatto salvo” non è inficiato da quanto detto in precedenza, e quindi continua a valere. “Salvo buon fine” potrebbe essere interpretato così: “fatta salva la necessità del buon fine”.

Answer (score 2):

Ritengo che "[salvo](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/salvo/)" nel primo caso sia erroneamente utilizzato<sup>1</sup>, e che nel secondo caso l'accezione intesa sia in effetti la **3** e non la **4b**:

> 3. In costruzione assoluta, è forma ellittica per «a condizione che sia salvo, che non patisca danno o pregiudizio»: deve prevalere l’interesse della comunità, salvi tuttavia i diritti dei singoli; si arresero, salvi la vita e gli averi, a condizione di conservarli. È usata anche l’espressione salvo il vero, se non mi sbaglio (propr.: sempre rispettando il vero, se questo fosse diverso da ciò che io affermo): s. il vero, la spesa si aggira sui cinquemila euro.

Dove "salvo" ha un valore più letterale e opposto a quello comunemente inteso di "ad eccezione di", e significa effettivamente citando letteralmente il Treccani "a condizione che sia salvo, che non patisca danno o pregiudizio".

Ovvero più precisamente nel secondo caso si intende "a condizione che il buon fine *sia salvo*" (o "a condizione che il buon fine *non patisca danno o pregiudizio*").

In effetti da questo punto di vista si potrebbe anche dire che sia più logico intendere "salvo" in questo modo piuttosto che come "ad eccezione di", anche se indubbiamente "ad eccezione di" è l'accezione più comunemente utilizzata e normalmente intesa.

---

1. Potrebbe essere stato utilizzato sia come nella **3** ma senza concordare l'aggettivo col genere (sarebbe dovuto essere "*salva* approvazione banca") che come nella **4b** ma volendo intendere effettivamente l'opposto, ma in ogni caso direi che sia scorretto.

Comment: "Salvo buon fine" appare nel Treccani nell'accezione 4b, ma concordo con te che sembra un caso particolare dell'accezione 3 e non dell'accezione 4: non sembra avere senso dire "eccetto buon senso".

Comment: @Charo Non me ne ero accorto. Grazie della segnalazione, comunque se il Treccani ha ragione allora non me lo spiego neanche io. Sarebbe semplicemente idiomatico dirlo in quel modo allora. Lascio qui perché potrebbe anche essere un'imprecisione del Treccani, ma se arriva una risposta migliore cancello.

Answer (score 0):

Nella tecnica bancaria italiana nella pratica commerciale in genere, la clausola di "salvo buon fine" significa che il titolo (il caso tipico riguarda un pagamento effettuato con assegno bancario, ma vale anche per il bonifico) viene accettato con **presunzione temporanea di validità** e dal momento dell'accettazione possono immediatamente farsi decorrere conseguenze pratiche del pagamento (ad esempio la consegna di un bene o l'erogazione di un servizio o l'esecuzione di una prestazione); tuttavia, l'eventuale successivo **mancato buon fine** comporta giuridicamente **che il pagamento non è stato effettuato.**

Il vantaggio di questa clausola è di consentire di dare immediato effetto alle obbligazioni contrattuali legate al pagamento, senza dover attendere i tempi per la negoziazione dell'assegno, che in Italia non è ancora in tempo reale, anzi ci mette una vita.